# ExecuteNonQuery always return 0

Tags: vb.net

I have an addEmployee form on my vb project which is connected to a database on my localhost. I want to check if an employee exist in the database before adding them. the code works fine and the employee is added when there is no similar entry in the database and not added when a similar entry exist. however, the messagebox always show "failed to add user" even though adding was successful. I tried to check what the value of ExecuteNonQuery is and it is always 0.

```
//the code in the addEmployee form

Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "addEmployee"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Employee_ID", tbNEmployeeID.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("First_Name", tbNFirstName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Last_Name", tbNLastName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Middle_Initial", tbNMiddleInitial.Text)

    conn.Open()

    MsgBox(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery)
    If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
        MsgBox("user succesfully added")
    Else
        MsgBox("failed to add user")
    End If

    conn.Close()

//db addEmployee procedure

begin

set @eid = Employee_ID;
set @fname = First_Name;
set @lname =Last_Name;
set @mi = Middle_Initial;
set @idexist = (select count(*) from user where EmployeeID = @eid);


if( @eid = '' or @fname = '' or @lname = '' or @mi = '') THEN select 
'Please fill out all empty parameters!';
 elseif(@idexist = 1) then select 'User already exist!';
 elseif(@idexist = 0) THEN
 insert into user values(id,@eid,@fname,@lname,@mi,now(),UpdatedAt);
 select 'User added successfully!';

end IF;
END
```

I want ExecuteNonQuery to return 0/1

I'm still new to this so if you can simplify answers.thank you

Comment: Does your stored procedure return a value? A stored procedure invocation is documented to return -1 in the ExecNonQuery documentation; the only things that actually change it are `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, and your execution isn't doing any of those directly because you're doing it in a stored procedure instead.

Comment: i don't think it returns a value. It just insert new entry in the database. thank you for your answer sir.

Comment: As I said, if your query does not start with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, then ExecuteNonQuery returns -1. Yours doesn't, so that's the value you're going to get back.

Comment: You can pass a parameter with direction output-only and get anything you want. Ken already mentioned the behaviour of the method (ExecuteNonQuery), but you still can return... [See direction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameter_Direction.htm) information here.

Comment: I was able to fix it finally. Thank you for your help sir Ken and sir Çöđěxěŕ :)